# Unrecognized option '/ruleset' in VS2015 during building

Tags: build, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015, rules

I have strange error during building my solution. Yesterday everything was fine, but today I get this error

Picture of error from error list:
[image]

Copy/paste error from output:

> fatal error CS2007: Unrecognized option: '/ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset"'

Solution contains many projects, but during building all solution, only one project show this error.
Does anyone can help me?

P.S. Changing file with ruleset did not help, I had the same error (but with other file in error message). But actually, I do not want change that ruleset file.

Comment: Please, copy error message instead of posting picture

Comment: Ok, I will copy that error for a moment

Comment: OK, I added the copied error message from output with error code

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the following link, try opening it in VS2013, turn off the ruleset, then open in 2015, and turn it back on.

src: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/974f66c6-debf-4a51-8463-00624e4dafa4/vs-2015-building-2013-project-could-not-find-rule-set-file-minimumrecommendedrulesruleset?forum=msbuild

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I had to reinstall my system (for some other reasons too). Since that I do not have the ruleset error. Probably because of that I am using only VS 2015.
So I can not confirm your solution. But maybe someone else will be have the same problem.